# How do I prevent draft posts from being accessible publicly?

Tags: posts, draft

I am currently having some issues with a site that has fairly high traffic where draft versions of posts are being linked directly and actually being hit dozens and in some cases hundreds of times.

Should draft posts even be accessible to bots and the Internet at large? If not, how are they coming through?

I currently use a redirect tool to redirect any draft posts to the live ones, but I would like to resolve this at the root level and keep draft posts from going out into the wild at all.

How do I prevent this?

Comment: Are the drafts revisions of published posts? Prior to the published version, or saved after the published version? I believe drafts that have never been published should not be visible to the public or bots. It could have to do with your theme or plugins - if something is querying all posts, and not restricting to published status, that could be what's providing the links to bots.

Comment: They are versions prior to published. I have suspicions about a plugin.

Comment: You could crawl your website with something like the free version of ScreamingFrog to see whether or not your own site is publishing links to those pages, and once you find out where the links are, it should help determine whether they're coming from a particular plugin or theme. You should also check any sitemaps in case they're lurking there.